# Srping/ Hibernate: spring.entity.Downloads cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have recently started trying to learn java and finished a spring/hibernate course in aims to implement a solution to some problems at work in my spare time. Needless to say, I have hit a snag.

I am wondering if anyone can see anything obviously wrong with the code attached below that can cause the following error:

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/sonya-local] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sonya.spring.entity.Downloads cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sonya.spring.entity.Downloads cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:429)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1495)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1507)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1485)
    at com.sonya.spring.dao.DownloadsDAOImpl.archiveProduct(DownloadsDAOImpl.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.archiveProduct(Unknown Source)
at com.sonya.spring.service.DownloadsServiceImpl.archiveProduct(DownloadsServiceImpl.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Basically I am looking to move data between tables after a small vetting period (1 hour) I have successfully added timestamps and a few other functions such as search, api calls etc so far.

The end goal of this is to attach a scheduler and have it run periodically throughout the day but for now I have added a url mapping to trigger it manually.

When hitting the URL I receive the above error:

My Code:

**Controller code**

```
 @GetMapping("/archiveproducts")
    public String archiveDownloads (){

         List<Downloads> theDownloads = downloadsService.getDownloads();


         for (Downloads archiveDownload : theDownloads)  {

            // display the download ... just for clarity
            System.out.println(archiveDownload);

            Date timer = new Date();
            Date purge = archiveDownload.getTimestamp();
            long hours  = (timer.getTime() - purge.getTime()) / DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_HOUR;

            if (hours >= 1) {

            downloadsService.archiveProduct(archiveDownload);

            }
        }
        return "list-downloads";
 }
```

**DownloadsDAOimpl Code: (java:128)**

```
public List<Downloads> archiveProduct(Downloads archiveDownload) {

    Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query theCopyQuery = 
            currentSession.createQuery("insert into Archive(fieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree, fieldFour, fieldFive, , fieldSix, FieldSeven)"
                    + "sfieldOne, fieldTwo, fieldThree, fieldFour, fieldFive, , fieldSix, FieldSeven from Downloads where id=:theId");
    theCopyQuery.setParameter("theId", archiveDownload);

    theCopyQuery.executeUpdate();

    List<Downloads> archiveProducts = theCopyQuery.getResultList();

    Query theDeleteQuery = 
            currentSession.createQuery("delete from Downloads where id=:theId");
    theDeleteQuery.setParameter("theId", archiveDownload);

    theDeleteQuery.executeUpdate(); 

   // return the results        
   return archiveProducts;
}
```

**DownloadsServiceImpl.java:65**

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<Downloads> archiveProduct(Downloads archiveDownload) {

    return downloadsDAO.archiveProduct(archiveDownload);
}
```

I understand that it's telling me I cannot cast an entity as an integer. but I don't understand where this integer is coming from or how to fix/reslove it.. I have a used a similar code approach for one of the API's and it worked okay.

```
@PostMapping("/listdownloads")
public List<Downloads> addDownloads (@RequestBody List<Downloads> theDownloads){

        for (Downloads tempDownload : theDownloads) {

        // display the download ... just for clarity
         tempDownload.setId(0);
         tempDownload.setTimestamp(null);
         System.out.println(tempDownload);

          // save to the database
          downloadsService.saveProduct(tempDownload);
        }
```

Cheers,

Danny

Comment: An insert query doesn’t return a result. So getResultList on an insert query doesn’t return a list of results if it returns anything it will return a row count.

Comment: Hi @M. Denium, thank you for your response. I believe I encountered this error when applying lucid's fix below. & changed the retrun type to 'public void archiveProduct'. Everything is working great now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with this line.

```
theDeleteQuery.setParameter("theId", archiveDownload);
```

It is expecting an integer as Id but you passing `Downloads` object as mentioned in eror message. you can try something like this.

```
theDeleteQuery.setParameter("theId", archiveDownload.getId());
```

Comment: Hi lucid, thank you for your response. I added the archiveDownload.getId() as you suggested and it got a few steps further, producing a different error  'hibernate hql ERROR: Not supported for DML operations'. I was able to resolve this one quite quickly though! thank you very much :)